# Added points are not showing in ArcGIS Online map viewer and dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, dashboard

I am new to GIS and ArcGIS Online platforms. I added an Excel(.csv) file first with relevant attributes. Then I hosted it and added 27 points by giving details of them in **ArcGIS map viewer classic**. When disabling editing points the popups show correctly in **ArcGIS map viewer classic**. But when viewing feature layer in **ArcGIS map viewer** points are not showing. My objective is to create a dashboard for this data. When I share data to a web app and create a dashboard any point is not visible there also.

Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: You have a tag for the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder but you make no mention of how it is relevant to your question.

Comment: I added that tag because my final purpose is to create a dashboard.

Comment: Can you modify the symbology of the layer, I've had several issues where symbology between classic and current just break.